# Homebrew installation for "virtualbox-extension-pack-beta" fails on macOS Ventura

Tags: homebrew, virtualization, virtualbox

##### Steps to reproduce

- install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)

```
 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

- install Virtualbox BETA

```
brew install --cask virtualbox-beta
```

- attempt to install virtualbox-extension-pack BETA

```
brew install --cask virtualbox-extension-pack-beta
```

- observe the error

```
 ==> Installing Cask virtualbox-extension-pack-beta
Password:
0%...NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to install "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/virtualbox-extension-pack-beta/6.1.0_BETA2,134221/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.0_BETA2-134221.vbox-extpack"
VBoxManage: error: The installer failed with exit code 1: VBoxExtPackHelperApp: error: Failed to set directory permissions on '/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/ExtensionPacks': VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
VBoxManage: error: rcExit=1
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ExtPackManagerWrap, interface IExtPackManager
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleExtPack(HandlerArg *)" at line 1904 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
==> Purging files for version 6.1.0_BETA2,134221 of Cask virtualbox-extension-pack-beta
Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/sudo -E -- /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage extpack install --replace /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/virtualbox-extension-pack-beta/6.1.0_BETA2,134221/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.0_BETA2-134221.vbox-extpack` exited with 1. Here's the output:
0%...NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to install "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/virtualbox-extension-pack-beta/6.1.0_BETA2,134221/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.0_BETA2-134221.vbox-extpack"
VBoxManage: error: The installer failed with exit code 1: VBoxExtPackHelperApp: error: Failed to set directory permissions on '/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/ExtensionPacks': VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
VBoxManage: error: rcExit=1
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ExtPackManagerWrap, interface IExtPackManager
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleExtPack(HandlerArg *)" at line 1904 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
VirtualBox Extension Pack Personal Use and Evaluation License (PUEL)
[...]
Do you agree to these license terms and conditions (y/n)?
License accepted. For batch installation add
--accept-license={{LICENSE}}
to the VBoxManage command line.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> VBoxManage: error: The installer failed with exit code 1: VBoxExtPackHelperApp: error: Failed to set directory permissions on '/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/ExtensionPacks': VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

It looks like the terminal application you used doesn't have permissions to create folders.

Depends on what terminal app you use. To me, I am using iTerm 2. So you can checkout [the official guideline](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/wikis/fulldiskaccess) to give full disk access to iTerm 2.

Afterward, I can install virtualbox-extension-pack without problem.

[image: Give Full Disk Access to iTerm]

Comment: thank you Gasol! your solution solves this error, now I get a different error, so it's progress I guess :)
if you feel like to follow up this is the "next" question
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/450627/brew-install-cask-virtualbox-extension-pack-beta-fails-with-failed-to-locat