# "brew install --cask virtualbox-extension-pack-beta" fails with "Failed to locate the main module ('VBoxPuelMain') "on M1 macOS Ventura

Tags: homebrew, virtualization, virtualbox

##### Steps to reproduce

0. grant disk access to your terminal (eg: [iterm2](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/wikis/fulldiskaccess) [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/417Wf.png))
1. install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)

```
 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

2. install Virtualbox BETA

```
brew install --cask virtualbox-beta
```

3. attempt to install virtualbox-extension-pack BETA

```
brew install --cask virtualbox-extension-pack-beta
```

- observe the error

```
➜  ~ brew install --cask virtualbox-extension-pack-beta

==> Caveats
Installing virtualbox-extension-pack-beta means you have AGREED to the license at:
  https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/VirtualBox_PUEL

==> Downloading https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.0_BETA2/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.0_BETA2-134221.vbox-extpack
Already downloaded: /Users/yakforward/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/b72b85c17b0bc37ffc8dfba2aa95c03d06b46f4a5c6cf9e0955a6417d7cadc44--Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.0_BETA2-134221.vbox-extpack
All formula dependencies satisfied.
==> Installing Cask virtualbox-extension-pack-beta
0%...NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to install "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/virtualbox-extension-pack-beta/6.1.0_BETA2,134221/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.0_BETA2-134221.vbox-extpack"
VBoxManage: error: Failed to locate the main module ('VBoxPuelMain')
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ExtPackManagerWrap, interface IExtPackManager
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleExtPack(HandlerArg *)" at line 1904 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
==> Purging files for version 6.1.0_BETA2,134221 of Cask virtualbox-extension-pack-beta
Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/sudo -E -- /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage extpack install --replace /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/virtualbox-extension-pack-beta/6.1.0_BETA2,134221/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.0_BETA2-134221.vbox-extpack` exited with 1. Here's the output:
0%...NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to install "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/virtualbox-extension-pack-beta/6.1.0_BETA2,134221/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.0_BETA2-134221.vbox-extpack"
VBoxManage: error: Failed to locate the main module ('VBoxPuelMain')
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ExtPackManagerWrap, interface IExtPackManager
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleExtPack(HandlerArg *)" at line 1904 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
[...]
```

## update

this may be an issue with the cellar itself
see this [issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/134061)

Comment: Have you try to install the stable distribution instead of beta? If so, what is the result?

Comment: to my knowledge only beta supports M1 at the time of writing

Comment: Sorry bro, I don't have any Apple silicon machines.

Comment: seems to be a widespread problem with the cellar
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/134061